# How to create a side chain in EOS

Tags: block-producer, sidechain

I heard that it is possible to make independent side chains in EOS. How can I create a side chain? Is there any documentation for that?

Answer (score 3):

No easy documentation exist yet. You can use the documentation for the [bios boot sequence](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence).

I'm working on a project to simplify this and explain the economics of a private blockchain based on EOSIO, it is called [eosinabox](http://eosinabox.com) soon there will be a step by step guide to create a private blockchain there.

Comment: Is this still on?

Comment: The [Bios boot sequence](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence) is the step by step guide. I'm using EOS in a Box for an easy web wallet secured by biometrics, either fingerprints or face id.